# Celery unexpectedly closes TCP connection

Tags: django, kubernetes, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using RabbitMQ 3.8.2 with Erlang 22.2.7 and having a problem while consuming tasks. My configuration is django-celery-rabbitmq. While publishing messages in a queue everything goes ok until the length of the queue reaches 1200 messages. After this point RabbitMQ starts to close AMQP connection with following errors:

```
...
2022-11-01 09:35:25.327 [info] <0.20608.9> accepting AMQP connection <0.20608.9> (185.121.83.107:60447 -> 185.121.83.116:5672)
2022-11-01 09:35:25.483 [info] <0.20608.9> connection <0.20608.9> (185.121.83.107:60447 -> 185.121.83.116:5672): user 'rabbit_admin' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
...
2022-11-01 09:36:59.129 [warning] <0.19994.9> closing AMQP connection <0.19994.9> (185.121.83.108:36149 -> 185.121.83.116:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'rabbit_admin'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
...
[error] <0.11162.9> closing AMQP connection <0.11162.9> (185.121.83.108:57631 -> 185.121.83.116:5672):
{writer,send_failed,{error,enotconn}}
...
2022-11-01 09:35:48.256 [error] <0.20201.9> closing AMQP connection <0.20201.9> (185.121.83.108:50058 -> 185.121.83.116:5672):
{inet_error,enotconn}
...
```

Then the django-celery consumer disappears from queue list, messages become "ready" and celery pods are unable to ack the message after the job is finished with the following error:

```
ERROR: [2022-11-01 09:20:23] /usr/src/app/project/celery.py:114 handle_message Error while handling Rabbit task: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 514, in channel
    return self.channels[channel_id]
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/project/celery.py", line 76, in handle_message
    message.ack()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/message.py", line 125, in ack
    self.channel.basic_ack(self.delivery_tag, multiple=multiple)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1407, in basic_ack
    return self.send_method(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 70, in send_method
    conn.frame_writer(1, self.channel_id, sig, args, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 186, in write_frame
    write(buffer_store.view[:offset])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 347, in write
    self._write(s)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I have noticed that the message size also affects this behavior. In the above case there are like 1000-1500 symbols in each message. If I decrease it to 50 symbols, then the threshold at which RabbitMQ starts to close AMQP connection shifts to 4000-5000 messages.
I suspect that the problem is with lack of resources for RabbitMQ, but I don't know how find what exactly is going wrong. If I run htop on the server, I see that 2 available CPU are not at high load at any time (loaded less than 20% each) and RAM is 400mb / 3840mb used. So nothing seems to be wrong. Is there any resource checking command for RabbitMQ? The tasks do not take long time to complete, about 10 seconds each.
Also maybe there are some missing heartbeats from the client (I had the problem earlier, but not now, there are currently no error messages about that).
Also if I run `sudo journalctl --system | grep rabbitmq`, I get the following output:

```
......
Мау 24 05:15:49 oms-git.omsystem sshd[809111]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=43.154.63.169  user=rabbitmq
Мау 24 05:15:51 oms-git.omsystem sshd[809111]: Failed password for rabbitmq from 43.154.63.169 port 37010 ssh2
Мау 24 05:15:51 oms-git.omsystem sshd[809111]: Disconnected from authenticating user rabbitmq 43.154.63.169 port 37010 [preauth]
Мау 24 16:12:32 oms-git.omsystem sudo[842182]:       ad : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/var/log/rabbitmq ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -f -n 1000 rabbit@XXX-git.log
......
```

Maybe here is another issue with firewall, but I don't see any error messages about that in `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@XXX.log`.
My Celery configuration on client is like:

```
CELERY_TASK_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 30
CELERY_BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 30
CELERY_BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 600
CELERY_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 1
CELERY_TASK_ACKS_LATE = True
```

Currently I'm running the pod using following command:
`celery -A project.celery worker -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log -Ofair`

Also I have tried to use various arguments to limit prefetch or turn off heartbit but it didn't work:
`celery -A project.celery worker -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --without-heartbeat --without-gossip --without-mingle`
`celery -A project.celery worker -l info -f /var/log/celery/celery.log --prefetch-multiplier=1 --pool=solo --`

I expect that there are no limitations on queue length and every celery pod in my kubernetes cluster consumes and acks messages without errors.